# can't understand following c++ code line

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new with C++, and try to figuring out what this line of code means:

```
cur_rect = cv::Rect(cur_rect) & cv::Rect(0, 0, mat->cols, mat->rows); // here
if( cv::Rect(cur_rect) == cv::Rect() )  //here
{
.......
}
```

Comment: It looks like the bitwise AND operator `&` has been overloaded for `Rect` - I'm guessing they are using it for intersection testing.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? is "&" that confuse you?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi : Yes!! "&" did confused me, I don't know whether this "&" is bitwise operator or adress of-pointer.. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Rect & Rect` part intersects two rectangles and gives a non-empty rectangle back when the two inputs overlap.

So you can compare the result to `Rect()` to see whether there was an intersection. Your code crops `cur_rect` to `(0, 0, mat->cols, mat->rows)` and then checks whether it is empty or not.

Sources:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html?highlight=rect

[How can one easily detect whether 2 ROIs intersects in OpenCv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714101/how-can-one-easily-detect-whether-2-rois-intersects-in-opencv)

### Edit

An alternative implementation, a bit cleaner:

```
// crop cur_rect to rectangle with matrix 'mat' size:
cur_rect &= cv::Rect(0, 0, mat->cols, mat->rows);
if (cur_rect.area() == 0) {
    // result is empty
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why does it construct a new `cv::Rect(cur_rect)` for the comparison, though - wouldn't `cur_rect` on its own do? And if `cv::Rect()` is an empty rect, isn't the `if` test inverted - it's testing whether the intersection is empty?

Comment: I think the `cv::Rect(cur_rect)` part is indeed extraneous, but it will work. Edited the response a bit, I think this is a sort of cropping-functionality.

Comment: I think I would implement the functionality as follows: `cur_rect &= cv::Rect(0, 0, mat->cols, mat->rows); if (cur_rect.area() == 0) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for replying @TaZ!! It helps me a lot.. =)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `cv::Rect(...)` methods (or family of them) returns a rectangle object. The line that you do not understand, I assume is an overloaded operator (`==`) that compares rectangles.

But I am making a lot of assumptions here as I do not have the code for `cv` class.

As to the `&` overloaded operator - one assumes that this is doing an intersection or union. Once again without the code it is hard to say.

Comment: See the "in addition to" paragraph in [the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#rect)